# Gradle: how to execute single test that has points and spaces in the name?

Tags: gradle, groovy

In Gradle one can execute a single test with spaces in the name like this:

`./gradlew test --tests 'com.sample.package.MyClass.my simple test'`

But I can't find a way for executing a test that is named like this:

`def "B.4.a. my simple test"()`

I tried this but it doesn't work, I guess because of the dots in the name itself:

`./gradlew test --tests 'com.sample.package.MyClass.B.4.a. my simple test'`

Though we use that to be able to map to our test documentation that has those sections `X.n.y` but I don't know if it's possible to escape the dots in the terminal to run a test named like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the dot "." in your test method name, you should be able to replace them with "*" on the commandline like:

```
./gradlew test --tests 'com.sample.package.MyClass.B*4*a* my simple test'
```

Comment: The * is a wildcard operator so if your test is the only test starting with B you could do:

    ./gradlew test --tests 'com.sample.package.MyClass.B*'